# npm ERR! Package-lock and package.json out of sync while runnin

Tags: node.js, json, angular, typescript, npm

I'm having an issue with NPM, it seems like package-lock and package.json are not synchronized with each other. I tried deleting node_modules, running npm install, but the problem still persists. Has anyone encountered such an issue?

npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.

npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Missing: tslint@3.15.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: diff@2.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: findup-sync@0.3.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: glob@7.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: optimist@0.6.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: underscore.string@3.3.6 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: glob@5.0.15 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: minimist@0.0.10 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: wordwrap@0.0.3 from lock file

Comment: I recommend deleting your package-lock file and node modules and running the npm install. This will create a new package-lock file.

Comment: @U.Aasd Unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

use

```
npm install --force
```

This should fix it in your local environment.

But be aware that your issue might be a persist when you try deploying your files to a server.

In that case you should deal with all conflicting packages.